# Angular JS change property of controller for directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to change boolean property of my controller from directive. It is set to true, but when i set it to false it should display other html template. Her is my code:

Directive code:

```
app.directive('entityTaskList', function(){
     return {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl: 'views/task/taskList.html',
     scope: {
         taskItems: '='
     },
     bindToController: true,
     controller: 'TasksCtrl as taskCtrl',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs){
         scope.openItem = function(){
             console.log("Open Items");
             var ctrl = scope.taskCtrl;
             ctrl.newTask = false;
         };
     }
   };
});
```

TaskCtrl code:

```
app.controller('TasksCtrl', ['$scope', 'TaskService', function ($scope,          TaskService) {
    // initialize function
    this.newTask = true;
    this.name = "Nedim";

    this.templates = {
        new: "views/task/addTask.html",
        view: "views/task/viewTask.html"
    };

    // load all available tasks
    TaskService.loadAllTasks().then(function (data) {
        $scope.items = data.tasks;
    });

    $scope.$on('newTaskAdded', function(event, data){
        $scope.items.concat(data.data);
    });

    return $scope.TasksCtrl = this;

}]);
```

taskList.html

```
 <ul class="list-group">
<li ng-repeat="item in taskCtrl.taskItems" class="list-group-item">
    <a ng-click="openItem()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true">   </span> 
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        <span class="task-description">{{item.description}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

and task.html

```
<!-- Directive showing list of available tasks -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <entity-task-list task-items="items"></entity-task-list>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" ng-controller="TaskDetailCtrl as taskDetailCtrl">
            <!-- form for adding new task -->
            <div ng-show="taskCtrl.newTask" ng-include="taskCtrl.templates.new"></div>
            <!-- container for displaying existing tasks -->
            <div ng-show="!taskCtrl.newTask" ng-include="taskCtrl.templates.view"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change this:

```
 // load all available tasks
TaskService.loadAllTasks().then(function (data) {
    $scope.items = data.tasks;
});
```

To this(literally):

```
 // load all available tasks
TaskService.loadAllTasks().then(function (data) {
    this.items = data.tasks;
});
```

your code will work, this is due to you using the controllerAs syntax for TaskCtrl but not assigning it to this instead to the $scope

Comment: P.S there is another line in the $scope.$on('newTaskAdded',..) where you are also using $scope instead of this